# useCallback is still leading to re-renders of children when parent's states change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Simplifying my app's components, I have a NoteList component with a particular child called FileTree. There are various states on NoteList. What I'm trying to do is to stop FileTree from re-rendering any time a state that only impacts NoteList changes. I'm getting tripped up on some functions that FileTree uses.

NoteList looks roughly like this:

```
const [folderName, setFolderName] = React.useState("")

...
const handleCreateFolder = React.useCallback(async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
    await axios.post(...call to create a folder...)
}, [])

const folderNameChangeHandler = React.useCallback((folN) => {
    setFolderName(folN)
}, [])

return (
...
    <FileTree prop1={prop1Value} prop2='prop2HardCoded' handleCreateFolder={handleCreateFolder} setFolderName={folderNameChangeHandler} />

)
```

Using the profiler, I still see that FileTree is re-rendering with every keystroke into a text input that uses `setFolderName` (or really, it should be using `folderNameChangeHandler` if I understand correctly) to change `folderName`.

What am I doing wrong with useCallback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `useCallback` is not going to prevent re-renders when using `setFolderName` because `setFolderName` is going to cause a re-render every time it is called.

Check out [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to control when `<FileTree />` re-renders.

You can use it to access previous and next props to determine if `<FileTree />` should re-render.

```js
function FileTree() {...}

export default React.memo(FileTree, (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  return true // this will never re-render

  // or do your custom logic to determine when it should re-render
})
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I especially appreciate how you specifically called out `return true // this will never re-render`, as that's the kind of simple fact about the method that would've taken me a while to figure out :)